# Python.h header missing

Tags: python, c, gcc, header-files

I'm trying to figure out how to compile Python modules in C (http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html), but the Python.h header file appears to be missing.

I've installed all the python development headers (I have Python-dev, python2.7-dev, python2.6-dev, python-all-dev) but gcc is still reutrning the error:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong here? Also is there an argument I need to add to gcc for Python.h (and what is it?).

Comment: Can you tell us what OS?

Comment: Did you try Geoff's suggestion? If it didn't work, add a comment to his answer to say what happened.

Comment: Still trying to figure it out. The documentation on this stuff is awful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `python-config` to determine the compile time and link time flags.

When compiling:

```
gcc -c `python-config --cflags` somefile.c
```

When linking:

```
gcc -o libfoo.so -shared `python-config --ldflags`
```

Though you really ought to think about using distutils as described in [Building C and C++ Extensions with distutils](http://docs.python.org/extending/building.html)

Comment: Sorted, thanks. Was going in the complete wrong direction there.