# Python 3.3 undefined references with static linking

Tags: c++, python, g++, static-linking, python-3.3

Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64

I've compiled libpython3.3m.a from source, along with the related headers. I wrote the following Makefile (specifically, look at my CFLAGS variable, which includes -lpython3.3m)...

```
BINS=python python-d
SOURCES=python.cpp

LIBROOT=/home/uberblah/lib/cpp
LIBDIR=$(LIBROOT)/lib
BINDIR=$(LIBROOT)/bin
INCDIR=$(LIBROOT)/include

CFLAGS= -I$(INCDIR)/python3.3m -L$(LIBDIR) -lpython3.3m

all: $(BINS)

python-d: $(SOURCES)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -g -o $@ $^

python: $(SOURCES)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean::
    rm -r -f *~ $(BINS)

edit::
    gedit $(SOURCES) Makefile &
```

And I wrote the following .cpp source file...

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Py_SetProgramName((wchar_t*)argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Typing make in the Makefile's directory results in the following messages.

```
g++ -I/home/uberblah/lib/cpp/include/python3.3m -L/home/uberblah/lib/cpp/lib -lpython3.3m -o python python.cpp
/tmp/ccBD4sLY.o: In function `main':
python.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Py_SetProgramName'
python.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
python.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
python.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [python] Error 1
```

Based on my understanding of the '-l' argument for g++, it is finding libpython3.3m.a, because otherwise it would tell me it was unable to find the library and exit.

So, if it's finding the library, why aren't these functions defined?

ADDITIONAL NOTES...

Built Python using --prefix and altinstall to have it install to a new directory (the one I'm pointing LIBROOT to in my makefile).

I have confirmed that libpython3.3m.a is in $(LIBDIR)

using nm to check for Py_SetProgramName...

```
uberblah@uberblah-N80Vm:~/lib/cpp/lib$ nm libpython3.3m.a | grep Py_SetProgramName
                 U Py_SetProgramName
0000000000001c00 T Py_SetProgramName
                 U Py_SetProgramName
```

Running Make verbosely...

```
    ...
    Finished prerequisites of target file `python'.
  Must remake target `python'.
g++ -I/home/uberblah/lib/cpp/include/python3.3m -L/home/uberblah/lib/cpp/lib -lpython3.3m -o python python.cpp
Putting child 0x00a585b0 (python) PID 16811 on the chain.
Live child 0x00a585b0 (python) PID 16811 
/tmp/cc2dom1S.o: In function `main':
python.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Py_SetProgramName'
python.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
python.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
python.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Reaping losing child 0x00a585b0 PID 16811 
make: *** [python] Error 1
Removing child 0x00a585b0 PID 16811 from chain.
```

If I split the compilation into an object stage then a binary stage, the binary stage fails with the same error message as originally mentioned.

Comment: What is your OS and addressing architecture?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64. I built Python using --prefix and make altinstall.

Comment: responded to second part of your question, added information to original post

Comment: Run `nm libpython3.3m.a`. These symbols are there?

Comment: Edited end of post to answer the nm question

Comment: Finally, lets see the compilation command itself. Ask `make` to be verbose.

Comment: Edited the text with the error output to include the command line that produced it. (see the error in the post). Oops...forgot verbose. Will edit in next 30 seconds.

Comment: Just a wild guess. Why don't you split compilation into 2 stages. First, compile the `python.cpp` into `python.o` and then link `python.o` with `libpython3.3m.a` into final executable.

Comment: The linking fails with the same error message.

Comment: For the record, if GCC does not find the library it will not inform you about it, but rather spit out `undefined reference` errors.

Comment: In the two stage compilation: on the second stage who goes the first `-lpython3.3m` or `python.o` in the command line?

Comment: The library is linked first. Also, when I used the incorrect name for the library, the linker stopped and reported "no such file".

Comment: Switched the order to 'g++ $(CFLAGS) -g -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)', where CFLAGS is only the include parameters and LDFLAGS is only the -L and -l parameters. No change.

Comment: You should be using `$(CFLAGS)` only one the **first** stage, and `$(LDFLAGS)` only on the **second** stage.

Comment: Like this: `g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^` to compile `python.o` and then `g++ python.o $(LDFLAGS) -o executable` to link `executable`.

Comment: Did that, but it appears to have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: Python actually installs with its own solution to this. It's talked about in this post (I knew my header wasn't missing, but I was being dumb and trying to link it all up myself, thinking "Oh, this is just what anyone needs to do to get Python working on my platform")...

[Python.h header missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622668/python-h-header-missing)